# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' Heroku

Tags: heroku, sqlalchemy, docker-compose

I an using Docker Compose with my app and database. My app connects to my database using the hostname `db` as shown in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
db:
    image: mysql
    # container_name: mysql_db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=test
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306`
```

But when I open my app on Heroku I get a connection error:

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")
```

I supposed  that this error appear because Heroku has dynamic hosts.
How can I set my database container up on Heroku?

Comment: It may actually be a good idea to run your application on a single server! A fully-replicated database often gives less cost. A MySQL interface to a version of SQLite with _ concurrency_ support may be a good idea; it can be scaled across different serves as load balancing. A self containing file based database seem be future proof in the long haul. I mean making apps dependent on a multitude of servers with different roles (with it's packages) not seldom break, my five cent with my 20 years of coding experience. Wordpress mostly came with MySQL pre 2022, so check for SQLite WP or litestream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I set my database container up on Heroku?

Don't.

One database container and one code container might make sense in development, but in production these things shouldn't be coupled. Use a hosted database provider instead; there are [several options](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores), including MySQL services, most of which have a free starter tier.

This matches [Heroku's recommendation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-development-with-docker-compose#pushing-your-containers-to-heroku):

> **Use Heroku add-ons in production**
>
> - **For local development:** use official Docker images, such as [Postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) and [Redis](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/).
> - **For staging and production:** use Heroku add-ons, such as [Heroku Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) and [Heroku Redis](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis).
>
> Using official Docker images locally and Heroku add-ons in production provides you with the best of both worlds:
>
> - **Parity:** You get parity by using the same services on your local machine as you do in production
> - **Reduced ops burden:** By using add-ons, Heroku – or the add-on provider – takes the ops burden of replication, availability, and backup.